# Injecting Window in angular 2 RC6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get access to Trello API using window object in angular 2 RC6. Before on different RC i used to import it like this:

```
import { window } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/browser';
```

i am doing the same now but i get a console error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js/src/facade/browser 404 (Not Found)
```

I removed this import thing and i realized i have access to the window without importing it because it seems to be defined on system.config.js like this

```
'@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
```

but the weird thing is when i console.log(window), i see Trello object and i also have access to the API using the methods, but typescript somehow doesn't know this or any other property inside window object

```
window.Trello // Property doesn't exist on type Window
```

I don't know but i am missing something, so Trello or any other property of window object works just fine but typescript does not have knowledge of these properties when it comes to require it but it knows that these properties exist when it comes to use it. I don't know if this makes sense :) I also realized when i run the server it fails with a message Property Trello doesn't exist on type Window. So basically window is just not injected or defined as it should.

Any idea will help a lot. Thanks In advance.

Comment: You need typings files to typescript to find these and not throw compiler errors.